# How can I Using LinQ search in a list by the input and print those that contain the letters?

Tags: c#, linq

Hi Im new to Linq and been trying to do this query but wont work, I have problems with the printing of the names, for example it does ask me the letters (inicials) I want, but when it comes to showing the matches they dont print

Here is the query:

```
        string input;
        Console.Write("Which fist 2 letters you want to look for? \n");
        input = Console.ReadLine();

        var search= from s in names
                     where s == input 
                     orderby s descending
                     select s;

        foreach (var name in search) 
        {
            Console.Write("\t" + name); 
            
        }
```

Here is my list:

```
string[] names= { "ANE", "CARL", "ANNA", "SOFIE", "ANNIE", "MARIE", "CAMILA", "SCOTT", "STILES", "JESSICA" };
```

The program does ask for the input but won't print anything as if there are no matches even when there are. How can I make results show up?

example of output
[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for a [StartsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-6.0)?

```
var search = names
  .Where(name => name.StartsWith(input))
  .OrderBy(name => name);
```

Comment: great clean example! and for op's code specially they can simply change `where s == input` to `where s.StartsWith(input)`